# Why map returns such unexpected result?

Tags: javascript

Probably noob JS question, but when we try to do this

```
new Array(5).map((_, index) => index);
```

we could expect to get something like 0,1,2,3,4 but we get an array of 5 empty elements. Why is that?

Comment: The issue here is that `new Array(5)` does not have any numerically-named properties. It only has a `length` property with the value `5`, but it has no properties named `0`, `1`, `2`, `3`, or `4`, as would exist on an array with 5 actual values. Since those properties don't exist, they are not handled by `map`.

Comment: @apsillers thanks, appreciated

Comment: `Array.from(Array(5), (_, index) => index);`